# Simple Timer in Meteor JS

Tags: meteor

I am creating a simple countdown timer for a game.  I am using CoffeeScript and Meteor.  I have a Handlebars "Timer" template with a {{time}} expression.

Here is the code:

```
clock = 10

timeLeft = () ->
    if clock > 0
        clock--
    else
        "That's All Folks"
        Meteor.clearInterval(interval)

interval = Meteor.setInterval(timeLeft, 1000)

if Meteor.isClient
    Template.timer.time = interval
```

The above code just gives me a static display of 8 or 6 instead of the countdown timer.

If I add a few console.log statements I can see it work as designed in the terminal.

```
clock = 10

timeLeft = () ->
    if clock > 0
        clock--
        console.log clock
    else
        console.log "That's All Folks"
        Meteor.clearInterval(interval)

interval = Meteor.setInterval(timeLeft, 1000)

if Meteor.isClient
    Template.timer.time = interval
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to update a value in handlebars you need to use `Session` so that its reactive, otherwise the Templating system won't be aware of when to update it in the ui. Also you passed the template a handler thats the handle instead of the timer value.

Using the below, I've used `Session` to pass this data through to handlebars.

```
clock = 10
timeLeft = ->
  if clock > 0
    clock--
    Session.set "time", clock
    console.log clock
  else
    console.log "That's All Folks"
    Meteor.clearInterval interval

interval = Meteor.setInterval(timeLeft, 1000)
if Meteor.isClient
  Template.timer.time = ->
    Session.get "time"
```

Also in javascript in case anyone else wants this:

```
var clock = 10;

var timeLeft = function() {
  if (clock > 0) {
    clock--;
    Session.set("time", clock);
    return console.log(clock);
  } else {
    console.log("That's All Folks");
    return Meteor.clearInterval(interval);
  }
};

var interval = Meteor.setInterval(timeLeft, 1000);

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.registerHelper("time", function() {
    return Session.get("time");
  });
}
```

In essence you tell `Session` the time value, and when its updated it tells the templating system to redraw with the updated time value.

Comment: Thanks Akshat.  Worked great.